# No match betweet dataset sparql dbpedia

Tags: graph, neo4j, sparql, dbpedia

i want to make a graph using 2 csv i got from dbpdia in NEO4J. the graph is about train in specific operational area and its start & end station.

this is my query to get train dataset

```
select distinct ?Nama_Kereta ?start ?end{ 
   ?n dbpprop-id:operator dbpedia-id:Daerah_Operasi_I_Jakarta.
   ?n rdfs:label ?Nama_Kereta.
   ?n dbpprop-id:start ?start.
   ?n dbpprop-id:end ?end.
}
```

and this is my query to get station dataset

```
select distinct ?Nama_Stasiun ?Kota_Kab { 
   {?n dcterms:subject <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Kategori:Stasiun_kereta_api_di_Jakarta>.
   ?n rdfs:label ?Nama_Stasiun.
   ?n dbpprop-id:kota ?Kota_Kab.} 
   UNION
   {?n dcterms:subject <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Kategori:Stasiun_kereta_api_di_Jakarta>.
   ?n rdfs:label ?Nama_Stasiun.
   ?n dbpprop-id:kabupaten ?Kota_Kab.} 
}
```

my problem is, when you look the result of train query the start & end station didn't have any match to station dataset. when I manually look to the one of station listed in train dataset (http://id.dbpedia.org/page/Stasiun_Tanahabang) it didn't have the **dbpprop-id:kabupaten** or **dbpprop-id:kota** properties. 
Is there any solution to make this station to appear in my station dataset ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but if the data is missing you have to get the data from somewhere else, i.e. you have to enrich your own dataset. You can only query for facts contained in the dataset, either explicitly or sometimes implicitly (via inference)

Comment: also, your second query can be simplified with SPARQL 1.1 property paths: `select distinct ?Nama_Stasiun ?Kota_Kab { 
   ?n dcterms:subject <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Kategori:Stasiun_kereta_api_di_Jakarta>.
   ?n rdfs:label ?Nama_Stasiun.
   ?n dbpprop-id:kota|dbpprop-id:kabupaten ?Kota_Kab. }`